# Multiple render outputs with different render engines at the same time?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have 1 model with 3 different outputs. 1 is an Octane render. The other 2 are a Face render, and a Wireframe, both using EEVEE. Is it possible to run all 3 renders at the same time using the different engines, and have different file locations?[image: Node Structure]